# Required ports 54321, 54322 are not available error on R in h2o

Tags: java, port, h2o

I am unable to start H2o in MRO3.3
the h2o.init() gave following output

```
08-02 00:40:36.543 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
08-02 00:40:36.610 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-turan
08-02 00:40:36.610 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Build git hash: e2959c131831f8d5dad8c92eebdf0ad4a4e78d09
08-02 00:40:36.610 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-rel-turan-3
08-02 00:40:36.610 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Build project version: 3.8.1.3
08-02 00:40:36.610 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Built on: '2016-03-06 14:54:19'
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 4
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 150.0 MB
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 1.72 GB
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_91 (from Oracle Corporation)
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-ea]
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: OS version: Linux 4.4.0-31-generic (amd64)
08-02 00:40:36.611 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 7.73 GB
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1470078635582
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: User name: 'chaithanya'
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Opted out of sending usage metrics.
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: wlo1 (wlo1), fe80:0:0:0:d5a6:487d:f375:a2e%wlo1
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: wlo1 (wlo1), 10.42.0.1
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: enp8s0 (enp8s0), fe80:0:0:0:1c9a:f547:b84:a5da%enp8s0
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: enp8s0 (enp8s0), 10.105.34.74
08-02 00:40:36.612 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
08-02 00:40:36.613 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
08-02 00:40:36.613 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      FATAL: On /127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again.
```

Output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
        at water.AutoBuffer.<init>(AutoBuffer.java:165)
        at water.UDPRebooted$T.send(UDPRebooted.java:25)
        at water.H2O.shutdown(H2O.java:519)
        at water.H2O.die(H2O.java:1770)
        at water.init.NetworkInit.initializeNetworkSockets(NetworkInit.java:410)
        at water.H2O.startLocalNode(H2O.java:1294)
        at water.H2O.main(H2O.java:1705)
        at water.H2OStarter.start(H2OStarter.java:21)
        at water.H2OStarter.start(H2OStarter.java:36)
        at water.H2OApp.main(H2OApp.java:5)
```

i can't access h2o even if i changed the port
i tried reinstalling java and h2o but no luck so far

Comment: What is "MRO3.3" ?  Are you on linux, or windows? And are you running on your local computer, or a remote machine?

Comment: this looks like a network configuration issue, I'm assuming you're on Windows (hence the MRO), can you run `netstat -an` from the command line and check if the ports you're trying to use are already being used by some other process?

Comment: I have similar error on Windows with R 3.3.1 and both ports are free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the log explains the issue:

```
08-02 00:40:36.613 127.0.0.1:54321       19672  main      FATAL: On /127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again.
```

It says, "some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available".  Make sure those ports are available, or if they can't be made available, then just start H2O on a different port using the `port` argument in `h2o.init()`.

Comment: Hi I have the same exact problem. Can't resolve it even if I specified a new port.

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli Are all your ports blocked?  Otherwise, setting to a different random port should work.